# Job title not matching the job activity

Tags: professionalism, resume, first-job, equity

I have recently landed my first professional job as an contract equity research analyst at a small firm through a friend. Generally speaking, such role requires one to have completed at least a bachelors degree whereas I have just completed my first year of Economics. I get paid no where near what an average person of such title gets.

My job is purely calling companies and asking for value opinions on how they are performing. The average equity research analyst has a much more demanding job activity. A high school kid could do what I do.

Now the problem is that how do I put this down on my CV if I still want to pursue a career in this field?
Would I say I have x years of experience as an equity research analyst?
Wouldn't a potential future employer raise concerns with my actual duties?

This is my first post with stack.e and I am looking forward to be joining the community.

Answer (score 4):

Don't get hung up with the "what i did", yes, you didn't do much.

*But* you have experience networking, gathering information, working in a team, working for a corporate (ie dressing presentably, socialising etc). Your probably didn't work the zillion hours that your peers would, either, which is probably a good thing.

You also have a strong in with your current team, or through their network, which is useful.

Just list your job as whatever title you had, and list your responsibilities, mentioning the soft skills & the capabilities you showed, along with the work you did. Also note the industry you focused on - look, you have more experience than other people at gauging if someone's profit/revenue share is bonkers, or if a 20% growth rate is likely. This stuff helps, and sells you - if only in whatever industry you worked on.

Did you work on any deals you can mention? Throw that in too.

You still don't have a degree and you're working part-time, nobody is going to assume you lead the team or anything fancy.

The best thing you can do is use the info you have now to work out which markets/industries are likely to boom in the next few years, and try to target them.

Comment: People in roles that require getting people outside the company to pay attention to them are sometimes given deliberately inflated titles. Potential employers will pay far more attention to what you actually did.

Answer (score 1):

Job titles are company dependent and can be arbitrary. Everyone hiring knows this which is why they look closely at duties performed and experience as well.

But if you had a fancy job title then you absolutely do have x years experience as a ~fancypants whatever~ at XXX company. and should list it as such.

Many many many people's jobs could be done by a reasonably bright High School student so don't let that worry you unduly. If nothing else x years of experience tells a hirer you have some sort of work ethic and can get out of bed and to work on time which is an asset in itself.